# Injecting a factory with dots in name

Tags: angularjs, mocking, jasmine

I need to use the angularjs mock inject method within Jasmine to inject a service with dots in the name. I tried to do add string identifiers but the inject method does not seem to support this. This is not possible:

```
beforeEach(inject(['$rootScope','MyApp.Factories.TestFactory', 
    function ($rootScope, testFactory) {

    //doSomeThing

}]));
```

Is there another way to handle this?

Comment: What's the purpose of the dots in the name? If you're trying to namespace why not just use modules?

Comment: Ok, I see your point but if I drop the namespace in the name for the controllers how will I tackle the following situation:

Let's say you have two modules
Module A & Module B and in each module you have a version of a controller with the same name e.g. MyCtrl

Which controller would be used  when referencing it in the view like this <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> ?

Comment: I guess I've never run in to the scenario in any of my angularapps, typically my modules are bounded logically by functional area and don't have services/controllers/directives that share names with others, but I can see how that could easily happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you can probably get it from the `$injector` yourself. Something like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$injector) {
    var testFactory = $injector.get('MyApp.Factories.TestFactory');
    //doSomeThing

}));
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually works. It would be nice though if the angular mock inject method would support string identifiers!